# move object in line curve in THREE.JS with tweenjs

Tags: animation, three.js, tween.js

I have an object that is a line. I would like to make an animation with an object that will move all vertices, it can be a sphere. for that I will use tween.js. my problem is that I can not achieve all its vertices animation. how I can do to make the animation is displayed from the start point to the end ?.
I have this code:

```
//myline.geometry.vertices  -> array with vertices of the line (1000 vertices)
new TWEEN.Tween( mysphere.position ).to( { x: myline.geometry.vertices[0].x, y: myline.geometry.vertices[0].y, z: myline.geometry.vertices[0].z }, 9000 ).to( { x: myline.geometry.vertices[1].x, y: myline.geometry.vertices[1].y, z: myline.geometry.vertices[1].z }, 9000 ).delay(2000).start();
```

[image]
I use the ".to" method and works well, if I put the vertices to which I want to move. method but if I have 1000 vertices, I would have to put them all. What can I do?.
I put several spheres moving at the same distance across the line. How can I do it?.
 I need to move a sphere along a line that is a mesh and have created earlier. I need to move n number of sphere along the line, making an animation. with tween.js should be more easy..

Answer (score 0):

While you have not specified how you want to determine where these vertices will move, I strongly suggest that you look into the `THREE.MorphAnimMesh` and `THREE.MorphBendMesh` types. By specifying the target positions in your geometry's definition, you can have smooth animation without needing to make complicated setups using tween.js -- just call the amount of blending, rather than a per-vertex loop. THREE.js will do all the work for you. You can also just use the basic `THREE.Mesh` type as in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets

If you do need to alter the geometry `.vertces` array, remember to set `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` after altering the values, so that THREE can be sure to update its internal WebGL representation of your model.

Comment: that answer does not help me, I need to move a sphere along a line that is a mesh and have created earlier. I need to move n number of sphere along the line, making an animation. with tween.js should be more easy..

Comment: then create an array that contans a copy of your desired vertices. Use this array to create a curve, e.g.  `c = THREE.SplineCurve3(verts);` now for the number of frames you want to animate across, get a new array of positions via `newPoints = c.getSpacedPoints(nFrames);` and then for each frame simply set the position to that point.   Alternatively, if you don't want fixed time steps, you can query it parametrically via `c.getPoint(t);` where t varies from zero to one.

Comment: thanks, I have no very clear that "Frames" and not understand "c.getPoint (t) Where t varies from zero to one". I do not think that with this I need to achieve animation. As the title says I need animation with tween.js

Comment: Something like
    `var t=0;
    var c = THREE.SplineCurve3(verts);
    function mvSphere(event) {
        sphere.position.copy().c.getPoint(t);
    }
    new TWEEN.Tween(t,{onChange:mvSphere).to(1.0,9000);`
Should do the trick. TWEEN only understands linear transitions between properties, so you need to use the `onChange` to perform more complex THREE transformations.